# U-boot doesn't show its terminal

Tags: beagleboneblack, u-boot

I have compiled the u-boot for beaglebone black but the only message that I can see is:

[image]

At [elinux.org tutorial](https://elinux.org/Building_for_BeagleBone) the expected result is some errors followed by the u-boot terminal available to use.

To build u-boot I've followed the steps:

```
$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- distclean
$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- am335x_evm_config
$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-
```

my SD Card is set like this:

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 28,89 GiB, 31002198016 bytes, 60551168 sectors
Disk model: SD/MMC/MS PRO   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x33bcefe5

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1  *       2048  2099199  2097152    1G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdd2       2099200 60551167 58451968 27,9G 83 Linux
```

Comment: U-Boot isn't initializing itself properly. You are almost certainly missing some `CONFIG_*` options that are required for your board. Are you using the BSP (Board Support Package) for your board? That should pre-define the `CONFIG_*` options that you need, based on the drivers, etc. I think that elinux.org tutorial is incomplete. [This tutorial](https://longervision.github.io/2018/01/10/SBCs/ARM/beaglebone-black-uboot-kernel/) suggests you need some patches for U-Boot.

Comment: Same issue is still happening with your tutorial too. I think the problem probably is caused by some hardware fail. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfotunetly I confirmed that was a hardware issue :(